# How to pass query parameters to url while testing rest service in swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui

I am using swagger UI to test spring boot rest services But I have to pass query parameters to URL like 
http://localhost:8080/v1.0/media/?user=dcisupportevg&client=20

How to pass those parameters?

Thanks in Advance.

```
@Bean 
public Docket productApi() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                  .apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO)
                  .select()
                  .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                  .basePackage("com.dci.rest.controller"))
                  .paths(regex("/.*"))
                  .build(); 
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/v1.0/media"})
public class MediaController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/" method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Response<Object> getAllMedia(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariablesMap,HttpServletRequest request){

        Response<Object> responseVO = new Response<Object>();
        try {
            responseVO = mediaService.getAllMedia(request,pathVariablesMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseVO;      
    }
}
```

But actually, I have to use URL:http://localhost:8080/v1.0/media/?user=xxxxx&client=xxxx to get response from above method.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you use Swagger UI the UI will provide fields to enter the parameters that are in the Swagger definition.

Comment: But it's not providing a box for parameters

Comment: Can you post your swagger definition file?

Comment: @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
   return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.dci.rest.controller"))
                .paths(regex("/.*"))
                .build();
             
    }

Comment: Ok and please also the RestController method

Comment: I shared RestController method above.

Comment: You have a map of variables. Swagger don't know what's inside the map. Why do you use a map?